# Segmentation fault when writing and printing the combination of two strings alternating between each one?

Tags: c

The goal is to take two strings(30 character maximum), for example "cat" and "dog", and print out "cdaotg"(alternate between strings). If one string is longer, it should print the rest of the longer string.
I am getting a segementation fault(core dumped) error either while writing the string or printing it, here is the relevant code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char str1[30], str2[30], newstr[61] = { '\0' };     //declarations
    printf("Please enter a maximum 30 characters: ");   //user input
    scanf("%s", str1);
    printf("Please enter a maximum 30 characters: ");
    scanf("%s", str2);

    if (*argv[1] == 'i') {     //if statement to check if command argument is 'i'
        char *newstr;   //declare pointer to first element of array "newstr"
        while (*str1 != '\0') {      // while the first string is not NULL 
            *newstr = *str1;      //value at newstr=value at str1
            newstr++;         //increment pointer
            *newstr = *str2;        //value at newstr=value at str2
        }
        *newstr = '\0'; //set the rest of newstr to null
        printf("The combined string is: %s", newstr);     //print out combined string 
    }
    else  //if command argument!='i', just print out nope
        printf("nope");
}
```

Comment: Why is your code formatted in this jumbled-up manner? Are you deliberately trying to make it difficult to read? Why?

Comment: I took the liberty of indenting your code a more widely accepted way.

Comment: You never change the value of `str` inside your `while (*str1 != '\0')`-loop.

Comment: If you don't provide any argument to the program when you run it, the test of `(*argv[1] == 'i')` yields undefined behaviour with a crash/segmentation fault being a likely manifestation of UB.  You should check that there is a non-null `argv[1]` before dereferencing it.  Also, your pointer `newstr` doesn't point at anything — more UB.  You must make sure your pointers point somewhere sane before using them.

Comment: @Swordfish `str1` and `str2` are arrays, so they can't be incremented. OP needs other pointer variables to traverse them.

Comment: @CraigEstey Then, Houston, that might be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix some of the errors mentioned in the top comments.

But, do *not* use the sub-scoped `char *newstr;`. It hides the `char newstr[61]` definition above (which you *do* want to use).

Your merge code needs some work:

```
char *dst = newstr;
const char *s1 = str1;
const char *s2 = str2;

for (;  (*s1 != 0) && (*s2 != 0);  ++s1, ++s2) {
    *dst++ = *s1;
    *dst++ = *s2;
}

for (;  *s1 != 0;  ++s1)
    *dst++ = *s1;

for (;  *s2 != 0;  ++s2)
    *dst++ = *s2;

*dst = 0;
```

Comment: how do I account for an entered hyphen into the argv array? Right now it works but you have to enter "./filename i", I would like to have the user be able to enter "./filename -i"? Thanks you by the way, I did basically that but used while loops.

Comment: @steakfry - either use `getopt` or manually parse the argument vector to determine the presence of `"-i"` as the next argument.

Comment: Your `while` loop, _as posted_, won't merge correctly. So, if you've got something working, it doesn't match the code here. An easy way to match the `-i` is to replace `*argv[1] == 'i'` with `strcmp(argv[1],"-i") == 0`. But, without further context, since you use `printf/scanf` to get your strings, I don't see why you need to look at `argv` at all since it's either a match or you're printing "nope" which doesn't seem to be that useful.